# Can one use gelatin while force carbing, or will CO2 keep gelatin suspended

Tags: carbonation, finings

New to world of finings. I figured i'd see if I could get a faster turnaround.

Right now I'm kegging, then conditioning/force carbing at the same time at 40F. Can I cold crash, then on the next day add gelatine and start force carbing?

Comment: wanting to wait to add gelatin until beer has had a chance to form possible chill haze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CO<sub>2</sub> won't keep the gelatin suspended - it will sink as normal.

The CO<sub>2</sub> pressure is evenly distributed throughout the keg and applies pressure equally in all directions. There's no more CO<sub>2</sub> pressure pushing down than there is pushing up, so Gravity will still produce a downwards force, and the gelatin will sink.

Comment: Ohhh I like that explanation of the evenly distributed pressure. Makes me feel smarter for having read it.

Comment: ok, going to go ahead and do my first gelatin addition on our amber ale. Aloha and Cheers

Comment: well everything worked nicely. Normally my kegs had to sit for 24 hours before serving because of the transportation from carbing fridge to second floor bar. The gelatin seems to hold everything down at the bottom when moving the keg. Sort of like a layer of heavy jello on top of all the trub.